# "tuple index out of range" reading pandas pickled Panel

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

data is a pandas Panel

`data
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 16 (items) x 1954 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ADRE to SPY
Major_axis axis: 2004-12-01 00:00:00+00:00 to 2012-08-31 00:00:00+00:00
Minor_axis axis: open to price`

Save to disk

```
pandas.to_pickle(data, 'data.pkl')
```

But when I try to read pkl file

```
pandas.read_pickle('data.pkl')
```

I get:

> `
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 print type(data)
>         2 data.to_pickle('G:\temp\test.pkl')
>   ----> 3 pd.read_pickle('G:\temp\test.pkl')
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\io\pickle.pyc
>   in read_pickle(path)
>        47 
>        48     try:
>   ---> 49         return try_read(path)
>        50     except:
>        51         if PY3:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\io\pickle.pyc
>   in try_read(path, encoding)
>        44         except:
>        45             with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
>   ---> 46                 return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
>        47 
>        48     try:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.pyc
>   in load(fh, encoding, compat, is_verbose)
>        87         up.is_verbose = is_verbose
>        88 
>   ---> 89         return up.load()
>        90     except:
>        91         raise
>
> C:\Python27\lib\pickle.pyc in load(self)
>       856             while 1:
>       857                 key = read(1)
>   --> 858                 dispatchkey
>       859         except _Stop, stopinst:
>       860             return stopinst.value
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.pyc
>   in load_reduce(self)
>        16     args = stack.pop()
>        17     func = stack[-1]
>   ---> 18     if type(args[0]) is type:
>        19         n = args[0].**name**
>        20         if n == u('DeprecatedSeries') or n == u('DeprecatedTimeSeries'):
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> `
>
> ---

I can work around this, but my question is "am I using to/from pickle correctly"?

Answer (score 2):

pickles are saved by:

```
 panel.to_pickle('file_name.pkl')
```

you don't appear to be using a string filename and are adding an extra (non quoted) argument.

reading is using a quote filename as well

```
 pd.read_pickle('file_name.pkl')
```

On python 27-32 bit on windows

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.1'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.13.1-791-g07f6d46'
>>> from pandas.util import testing as tm
>>> panel = tm.makePanel()
>>> pd.to_pickle(panel,'test.pkl')
>>> pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

So not sure EXACTLY what data, maybe show a reproduction

Comment: oops, sorry, my mistake! I've edited the original post with the correct code - the error is as stated.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.  It's an incompatibility between `pandas` and `pytz`.   Issue is here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6871

You can work around it by directly unpickling:

`with open('file_name.pkl', 'rb') as f:
      panel = pickle.load(f)`